# Spotfire case statement

Tags: spotfire, case-statement

I need to create a case statement in Spotfire please help.

Case WHEN UniqueCount([Product])<5 then UniqueConcatenate([Product]) else "Multipl Products" 
WHEN UniqueCount([Division])<5 then UniqueConcatenate([Division]) else "Multipl Dev" END

Comment: Are you getting an error message? As written, if there is more than 5 products or divisions in your table, you will always hit the multiple. Should you be counting over a subset of records instead of all of them?

Comment: It looks to me like you actually want this to be two separate columns.

Answer (score 0):

per the [documentation](https://docs.tibco.com/pub/spotfire/6.5.2/doc/html/ncfe/ncfe_logical_functions.htm), CASE statements are only allowed a single ELSE. also I am assuming based on the provided example that you need two separate columns.

column 1 [Products]:

```
CASE 
  WHEN UniqueCount([Product])<5 then UniqueConcatenate([Product]) 
  ELSE "Multiple Products" 
END
```

column 2 [Divisions]:

```
CASE
  WHEN UniqueCount([Division])<5 then UniqueConcatenate([Division]) 
  else "Multiple Divisions" 
END
```

if this doesn't answer, please edit your question for clarity.